# How to handle an empty param in Kotlin?

Tags: json, gson, kotlin

In java we can do following

```
class A{
  int id;
  String name;

  public A(){}
  public A(int id, String name){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
  // getter/ setter
}
```

then I can create a new Object and get json as following

```
A a= new A()
a.setName("test")

System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(a))
```

which gives me the result

```
{"name":"test"}
```

In kotlin how can i achive this?

The problem I am facing is kotlin saying primitive type has to be initialized. So in json I am getting both `id` and `name`; which i don't want

So how to do this???

Comment: Are you sure you have `int id;` and not `Integer id;` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kotlint treats [null safety seriously](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) thus you have to be explicit about the initialization values. Your example can be translated to:

```
class A(var id: Int? = null, var name: String? = null)
```

Notice that the above has both [default arguments](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#default-arguments) and a [parameterless constructor on the JVM](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#secondary-constructors). This let's you write:

```
val a = A()
```

As well as:

```
val a = gson.fromJson(json, A::class.java)
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid this. But I guess this is the only way

Comment: The secondary constructor isn't necessary, is it? The example could simply be `class A(var id: Int? = null, var name: String? = null)`

Comment: @mfulton26 the parameterless constructor is used by `gson.fromJson(json, A::class.java)`

Comment: `gson.fromJson(json, A::class.java)` works for me without `constructor() : this(null, null)`. This is because "on the JVM, if all of the parameters of the primary constructor have default values, the compiler will generate an additional parameterless constructor which will use the default values. This makes it easier to use Kotlin with libraries such as Jackson or JPA that create class instances through parameterless constructors." ([Secondary Constructors - Classes and Inheritance - Kotlin Programming Language](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#secondary-constructors))

Answer (score 1):

How about `lateinit`?

```
/* ***************************************************************************/
class A() {
  lateinit var id : Integer // Integer instead of Int due to lateinit's no-primitives requirement
  lateinit var name : String

  constructor(id : Integer, name : String) : this() {
    this.id = id
    this.name = name
  }
}
/* ***************************************************************************/

/* ***************************************************************************/
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val a = A()

  a.name = "test"

  assert(Gson().toJson(a) == """{"name":"test"}""")

  val aFromJson = Gson().fromJson("""{"name":"test"}""", A::class.java)

  assert(a.name == "test")
}
/* ***************************************************************************/
```

The advantage of using `lateinit` is the lack of nullable properties inside the class thus, you avoid dealing with a bunch of null checking and `?.` derefering.

Comment: Keep in mind that the lateinit properties will cause `UninitializedPropertyAccessException` if uninitialized when accessed, eg `Gson().fromJson("{}", A::class.java).name`